# How to set frame for all pages

Tags: php, html

I am creating a website in which the site is framed.
For better [visit](http://cocvidarbha.epizy.com/) here, it has the page of http://cocvidarbha.epizy.com/voting.

Now I want to visit http://cocvidarbha.epizy.com/voting/1.php. But the URL should be seen as http://cocvidarbha.epizy.com/ only.

I have only used `frame source` in `index.php` of http://cocvidarbha.epizy.com/

Comment: Put a link in `index.php` to `1.php` and see what happens if you click that link. PS: Make sure that `1.php` is an existing page.

Comment: I tried, @KIKOSoftware but it says page notfound..

Comment: That's because it didn't exist. First make page `1.php`, and then use the link in `index.php`.

Comment: I couldn't understood.

Comment: Well you can use a framework for this like laravel 5. I love that PHP framework. Or you can use the http POST in stead of a GET https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: I didn't get the answer with (w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: iframes are so 90s, try Ajax instead

Comment: Can you have some example of using ajax @user3284463

Comment: @ShriSun Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more of an client-side answer.

**Option 1:**

What you can do is tell the browser to change the URL to something else you desire(could also be an non-existing path). Note, you will not be able to change your domain name.

So, in your `1.php` file add:

```
<script>
    window.history.pushState("{data: 'pass data'}", "PageTitle", "/url");
</script>
```

within in the `head` tag.

**Option: 2**

Another way I would recommend is using Ajax.

You could bind all your `<a href="/url">`, so that when you click it, it returns the data on that url Asynchronously, without reloading the page.

So, in you main `index.php` file, add:

```
<li>
  <a href="http://cocvidarbha.epizy.com/">Page 1</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="http://cocvidarbha.epizy.com/voting/1.php">Page 2</a>
</li>

<div id="content">
  Content will be loaded here without any page reload or URL change
</div>
```

And then just before `</body>`, add:

```
// Include jQuery
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(e) {

  // Bind click event to all "<a>" tags
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    // Do Ajax Call to "href" clicked
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
      }
    })
    return false;
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the voting php either only or part of your index page,  you can always embed it into your index page. If the content is dynamic, this is one solution, as it avoids having to use frames (not supported in HTML5) / 301 redirects/ etc..

You could use [php include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to embed the file. The embedded file will update on the index page as the php file on the server. As jagb suggested below, it would be advisable to use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) when including a file; it will return an error message if the file does not exist.

e.g.:

```css
@media (orientation: portrait) { 
    body, .reorientMessage{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .mainContent{
        visibility: hidden ;
    }
}
@media (orientation: landscape) { 
    .reorientMessage{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    body,.mainContent{
        visibility: visible ;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="reorientMessage">please reorient etc..</div>
<div class="mainContent"><p>normal stuff here</p>
<br><br></div>
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/1.php';?>

</body>

</html>
```

[html above taken from the source output from your index page - 1.php embedded]

The [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) php function will read the contents of the 1.php file and return the contents as a string.

You can embed it similarly using

```
<?php
$1 = file_get_contents('./yourserverpath/1.php');
echo $1;
?>
```

where $1 is your variable that holds the contents of the file (and subsequently spits them out! :) )

so your final index page code would look like this:

```css
@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body,
  .reorientMessage {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .mainContent {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  .reorientMessage {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  body,
  .mainContent {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="reorientMessage">please reorient etc..</div>
  <div class="mainContent">
    <p>normal stuff here</p>
    <br><br></div>

<?php
$1 = file_get_contents('http://cocvidarbha.epizy.com/voting/1.php'); 
//I'm putting in the url cos i don't know your path but use the suggested 
//method -  $1 = file_get_contents('./yourserverpath/1.php');
echo $1;
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you won't see the php in the stack snippet, you should see it on your own server though

Comment: Just a note to your answer: You might want to change line #13 `<?php include 'http://www.cocvidarbha.epizy.com/voting/1.php;?>` to  `<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/voting/1.php';?>` as you'll need to close the single quot and if you would liket to use http URLs, it's better to try `readfile()` or `file_get_contents()` or any others such as `CURL` http url used in `include()` should never see production so it's bad to tell the OP to do so! Please consider to update your answer

Comment: You're Welcome, I hope your final answer will be helpful to the Stack Overflow community, happy coding

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do the **redirection** from the default landing page ( **index.php** ) into required page ( **1.php** ), By adding the below lines in your index.php code,

```
header("location:voting/1.php");
exit;
```

If you want to use the **frame** tag only without any redirection for url show, Change **src** attribute value into **voting/1.php**

Answer (score 1):

Try by using the following example where I have a Link and Iframe in my webpage.

```
<a id="myLInk" href="ClickMe.html" target="myIFrame"> Click Me </a>
```

Here `target="myIFrame"` will make the link to open in the IFrame with Id "myIFrame".

And this is my Iframe.

```
<iframe name="myIFrame" src="index.html" align="top" height="500" width="95%" hspace="10" vspace="10" align="middle">
If you can see
this, your browser does not support iframes!
</iframe>
```

Now when you click on the above link with Id "myLInk", then the link source (i.e, ClickMe.html) will be loaded in the iframe.
In this way you can load as many links as possible without navigating to the new page.
And this will remain the url unchanged.